# How to disable Starlette static files caching?

Tags: python-3.x, starlette

I am using the Starlette framework in a Python application with the static files configured as required by the documentation:

```
routes = [
...
Mount('/static', app=StaticFiles(directory='static'), name="static"),]
```

The problem is that Starlette is performing automatic caching of these static files and there is no information in the documentation on how to disable the cache.

I tried asgi-caches but I quickly saw that it configures the cache but can't seem to disable the cache right now.

The only mention of disabling the cache in the documentation informs you that it is an "TODO" and is a decorator to deals with views but not static files.

Does anyone know how configure the framework to guarantee that Starlette do not cache my static files?

Answer (score 3):

Seems no official configure to do that.

But you can do it by overwrite the method `is_not_modified` of `starlette.staticfiles.StaticFiles`.

Example:

```
from starlette.staticfiles import StaticFiles

class MyStatics(StaticFiles):

    def is_not_modified(
            self, response_headers: Headers, request_headers: Headers
    ) -> bool:
        # your own cache rules goes here...
        return False

...

Mount('/static', app=MyStatics(directory='static'), name="static"),]
```

Comment: Concise one liner is a monkey patch:


```StaticFiles.is_not_modified = lambda *args, **kwargs: False```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Xiwei Wang unfortunately didn't work for me.

This answer describes how to subclass `StaticFiles` and modify the headers as needed. The question is about configuring/enablng caching: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77618845

Here's the snippet from the answer:

```
class StaticFilesCache(StaticFiles):
    def __init__(self, *args, cachecontrol="public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000, immutable", **kwargs):
        self.cachecontrol = cachecontrol
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def file_response(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        resp: Response = super().file_response(*args, **kwargs)
        resp.headers.setdefault("Cache-Control", self.cachecontrol)
        return resp


app.mount(
        path="/static",
        app=StaticFilesCache(directory=settings.STATIC_DIRECTORY, cachecontrol="private, max-age=3600"),
        name="static",
    )
app.mount(path="/sphinx", app=StaticFilesCache(directory=settings.SPHINX_DIRECTORY, html=True), name="sphinx")
```

To disable the cache, we need to modify the headers in the opposite direction.

I found this article, which describes the headers used by major websites to disable caching: https://fred-gu.medium.com/fix-the-annoying-web-page-caching-issue-permanently-5d16527d0b5a

It summarizes by suggesting these headers for the strictest no-caching behaviour:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Putting the two together, we end up with this:

```
from typing import Any

from starlette.responses import Response
from starlette.staticfiles import StaticFiles


class NoCacheStaticFiles(StaticFiles):
    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any):
        self.cachecontrol = "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, , must-revalidate"
        self.pragma = "no-cache"
        self.expires = "0"
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def file_response(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Response:
        resp = super().file_response(*args, **kwargs)
        resp.headers.setdefault("Cache-Control", self.cachecontrol)
        resp.headers.setdefault("Pragma", self.pragma)
        resp.headers.setdefault("Expires", self.expires)
        return resp
```

This works for me, and my static files are not cached.