# How to add custom headers to static files in fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, static, fastapi

We are using the following method to mount the static files from a directory
 `app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")`

We have sent a custom headers for api for security related steps using a common method before sending response to the client.

Is there a way to send the security headers to css/js/html static files the same kind of headers. ?

Just want to know, the way or approach to send custom headers to static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/static/{file_path:path}")
async def function(file_path: str):
    response = FileResponse(f"static/{file_path}")
    response.headers["X-Custom-Header"] = "Your custom header value"
    return response
```

and you can see more [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-headers/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. When I try to implement the above logic. API doesn't hit even after loading the static files from the application.

Comment: Solution works after commenting the following line --- >> **app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=**  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class StaticFilesCache(StaticFiles):
    def __init__(self, *args, cachecontrol="public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000, immutable", **kwargs):
        self.cachecontrol = cachecontrol
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def file_response(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        resp: Response = super().file_response(*args, **kwargs)
        resp.headers.setdefault("Cache-Control", self.cachecontrol)
        return resp


app.mount(
        path="/static",
        app=StaticFilesCache(directory=settings.STATIC_DIRECTORY, cachecontrol="private, max-age=3600"),
        name="static",
    )
app.mount(path="/sphinx", app=StaticFilesCache(directory=settings.SPHINX_DIRECTORY, html=True), name="sphinx")
```

https://github.com/lexxai/goit_python_web_hw_14/blob/a4e247e2b1afb57f2d8eb9e63a34d34f4f3e6bd6/hw14/main.py#L99